¿Por qué el display cuádruple se muestra con menos intensidad?
Estoy desarrollando un código de arduino que a partir de un rtc y un dht muestre la hora y temperatura ambiente.
Muestra la temperatura con una buena intensidad de luz todos los dígitos. Sin embargo al momento de mostrar la hora se ve con menos intensidad y de manera degradada, es decir los últimos digitos con menos luz y el último ya con casi nada.
El código es el siguente:
void loop() {

  unsigned long currentTime = millis(); 
  while (millis() - startTime < 2000) {
     hora();
  }
  startTime = millis();
  while (millis() - startTime < 2000) {
     temperatura();
  }
  startTime = millis();
}

Para encender la hora es el siguiente (la función de la temperatura tiene la misma lógica):
void hora(){
  // This allows for the update of variables for time or accessing the individual elements.
  myRTC.updateTime();

  int hora= myRTC.hours;
  int minutos= myRTC.minutes;

  // Determinar cuántos dígitos tiene la temperatura redondeada
  int numDigits = 1; // Por defecto, asumimos un solo dígito

  if (hora >= 10) {
     numDigits = 2; // Si la temperatura es mayor o igual a 10, tiene dos dígitos
  }

  // Almacenar los dígitos en un array
  int digits[2];

  if (numDigits == 1) {
     digits[0] = hora; // Solo hay un dígito, almacenamos el valor directamente
  } else {
     digits[0] = hora / 10; // Primer dígito (decenas)
     digits[1] = hora % 10; // Segundo dígito (unidades)
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < numDigits; ++i) {
     switch (digits[i]) {
        case 0:
           cero();
           break;
        case 1:
           uno();
           break;
        case 2:
           dos();
           break;
        case 3:
           tres();
           break;
        case 4:
           cuatro();
           break;
        case 5:
           cinco();
           break;
        case 6:
           seis();
           break;
        case 7:
           siete();
           break;
        case 8:
           ocho();
           break;
        case 9:
           nueve();
           break;
     }

     // Mostrar el dígito actual en el display correspondiente
     switch (i) {
        case 0:
           if (numDigits == 1) {
              prender2(); // Solo encender el segundo display si numDigits es 1
              apagar();
              apagar2();
           }
           else{
              prender1();
              apagar();
              apagar2();
           }
           break;
        case 1:
           prender2();
           apagar();
           apagar2();
           break;
     }
  }

  ///////////////////////////////////////////MINUTOS///////////////////////////////////////////

  int numDigits2 = 1; // Por defecto, asumimos un solo dígito

  if (minutos >= 10) {
     numDigits2 = 2; // Si la temperatura es mayor o igual a 10, tiene dos dígitos
  }

  // Almacenar los dígitos en un array
  int digits2[2];

  if (numDigits2 == 1) {
     digits2[0] = minutos; // Solo hay un dígito, almacenamos el valor directamente
  } else {
     digits2[0] = minutos / 10; // Primer dígito (decenas)
     digits2[1] = minutos % 10; // Segundo dígito (unidades)
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < numDigits2; ++j) {
     switch (digits2[j]) {
        case 0:
           cero();
           break;
        case 1:
           uno();
           break;
        case 2:
           dos();
           break;
        case 3:
           tres();
           break;
        case 4:
           cuatro();
           break;
        case 5:
           cinco();
           break;
        case 6:
           seis();
           break;
        case 7:
           siete();
           break;
        case 8:
           ocho();
           break;
        case 9:
           nueve();
           break;
     }

     // Mostrar el dígito actual en el display correspondiente
     switch (j) {
        case 0:
           if (numDigits2 == 1) {
              prender4();
              apagar();
              apagar2();
              prender3();
              cero();
              apagar();
              apagar2();
           }
           else{
              prender3();
              apagar();
              apagar2();
           }
           break;
        case 1:
           prender4();
           apagar();
           apagar2();
           break;
     }
  }
}

Cada número lo hago de esta manera:
void cero(){
  digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(B, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(E, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G, LOW);

}
Cada dígito lo prendo de esta manera
void prender1() {
  digitalWrite(digito1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(digito2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(digito3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(digito4, HIGH);

}
Apago cada número así:
void apagar() {
  digitalWrite(A, LOW);
  digitalWrite(B, LOW);
  digitalWrite(C, LOW);
  digitalWrite(F, LOW);
  digitalWrite(E, LOW);
  digitalWrite(D, LOW);
  digitalWrite(G, LOW);

}
Y esta funcion es para apagar todos los dígitos
void apagar2() {
  digitalWrite(digito1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(digito2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(digito3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(digito4, HIGH);
}
  


Tienes un display con cuatro digitos en los cuales muestras alternativamente HHMM y luego la temperatura. ¿Correcto?

Si, es eso exactamente

Como es el circuito? Hay algunos que por simplificar solo ponen una resistencia en el ánodo/cátodo común y eso hace que se redistribuya la corriente, produciendo efectos como el de degradar la intensidad del display

Digamos que tienes la hora Hd Hu Md Mu (hora-decenas, hora-unidades, Minuto-decenas, Minuto-unidades)
Bueno, algo me parece sospechoso. Al mostrar los minutos, haces esto:
 switch (j) {
    case 0:
       if (numDigits2 == 1) {
          prender4();          // Prendes Mu
          apagar();            // Apagas todo (incluido Mu)
          apagar2();           // ¿Por qué apagas la Hu?
          prender3();          // Prendes Md.
          cero();              // Cambias los segmentos
          apagar();            // Apagas todo
          apagar2();           // y vuelves a apagar Hu
       }
       else{
          prender3();          // Prendes Md
          apagar();            // Apagas todo
          apagar2();           // y vuelves a apagar Hu
       }
       break;
    case 1:
       prender4();             // Prendes Mu
       apagar();               // Apagas todo
       apagar2();              // y vuelves a apagar Hu
       break;
 }

Ese parece ser el problema: prendes y de inmediato apagas.
Observaciones
Tienes código repetido. Te sugiero refactorizar, es decir, extraer el código en funciones que puedas ocupar más de una vez.
Este es una refactorización tentativa de tu rutina hora() (no tengo el hardware para probar).
void hora() {
  myRTC.updateTime();

  int hora = myRTC.hours;
  int minutos = myRTC.minutes;

  apagar();
  mostrar(hora, 1);
  mostrar(minuto, 3);
}

void mostrar(int valor, int posicion) {
  //  Muestra un valor 0-99 en el digito posicion y posicion + 1
  activar_segmentos(valor / 10);
  activar_display(posicion);
  activar_segmentos(valor % 10);
  activar_display(posicion + 1);
}

void activar_segmentos(int value) {
  //  Prende los segmentos correspondientes al valor
  switch (value) {
    case 0:
      cero();
      break;
    case 1:
      uno();
      break;
    case 2:
      dos();
      break;
    case 3:
      tres();
      break;
    case 4:
      cuatro();
      break;
    case 5:
      cinco();
      break;
    case 6:
      seis();
      break;
    case 7:
      siete();
      break;
    case 8:
      ocho();
      break;
    case 9:
      nueve();
      break;
  }
}

void activar_display(int posicion) {
  //  Prende el digito dada la posicion
  switch (posicion) {
    case 1:
      prender1();
      break;
    case 2:
      prender2();
      break;
    case 3:
      prender3();
      break;
    case 4:
      prender4();
  }
}
 

Las funciones mostrar(), activar_segmentos() y activar_display() también te servirán para mostrar la temperatura.
Pendiente Sacar los ceros a la izquierda del display.
